# graph paper size, format of the page?

Tags: graphics

I have a big graph and have a problem with paper size\format of the page. On my .pdf file I can see only 1\4 of this graph. i tried to "play" with size of the page but couldnot do anything. Are there methods to zoom out my graph or to do something with page size?

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[papersize={500mm, 1000mm}, text={90mm, 90mm}]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture} [
      line/.style = {draw, semithick, -latex},
      dot/.style = {draw, fill=black},
      ]


             \coordinate (0) at (0cm, 0cm);
             \coordinate (1) at (-20cm, 9cm);
             \coordinate (9) at (20cm, 9cm);


      \coordinate (2) at (-40cm, 30cm);
      \coordinate (8) at (40cm, 30cm);

      \coordinate (3) at (-40cm, 50cm);
      \coordinate (7) at (40cm, 50cm);



            \coordinate (4) at (-30cm, 70cm);
            \coordinate (6) at (30cm, 70cm);


            \coordinate (5) at (0cm, 85cm);


            \coordinate (10) at (0cm, 5cm);


             \coordinate (11) at (-15cm, 15cm);
             \coordinate (16) at (15cm, 15cm);


      \coordinate (12) at (-10cm, 22cm);
                  \coordinate (15) at (10cm, 22cm);


      \coordinate (13) at (-25cm, 26cm);
            \coordinate (14) at (25cm, 26cm);


      \coordinate (22) at (-30cm, 57cm);
      \coordinate (18) at (30cm, 57cm);


            \coordinate (19) at (0cm, 43cm);

            \coordinate (20) at (0cm, 55cm);


            \coordinate (21) at (-20cm, 45cm);
            \coordinate (17) at (20cm, 45cm);


             \coordinate (23) at (-12cm, 40cm);
      \coordinate (24) at (12cm, 40cm);


      \coordinate (25) at (8cm, 51cm);


            \coordinate (26) at (-30cm, 34cm);
            \coordinate (27) at (30cm, 34cm);

      \draw (0) -- (1);
      \draw (0) -- (9);
      \draw (0) -- (10);
      \draw (0) -- (16);
      \draw (0) -- (11);

      \draw (1) -- (10);
      \draw (1) -- (2);
      \draw (1) -- (11);


      \draw (2) -- (4);
      \draw (2) -- (3);
      \draw (2) -- (22);


      \draw (3) -- (4);
      \draw (3) -- (22);


      \draw (4) -- (5);
      \draw (4) -- (6);
 \draw (4) -- (20);
  \draw (4) -- (22);


      \draw (5) -- (6);
      \draw (5) -- (20);


      \draw (6) -- (20);
        \draw (6) -- (7);
      \draw (6) -- (18);
       \draw (6) -- (8);

        \draw (7) -- (18);
      \draw (7) -- (8);

            \draw (9) -- (8);

            \draw (9) -- (16);
            \draw (9) -- (10);

    \draw (16) -- (15);


      \draw (10) -- (11);
        \draw (10) -- (16);
      \draw (11) -- (12);
       \draw (12) -- (13);

      \draw (12) -- (27);
      \draw (12) -- (23);
       \draw (13) -- (27);
      \draw (13) -- (23);


      \draw (14) -- (26);
      \draw (14) -- (24);
       \draw (14) -- (15);
      \draw (15) -- (26);
      \draw (15) -- (24);

       \draw (17) -- (18);
      \draw (17) -- (25);
      \draw (17) -- (27);

      \draw (18) -- (25);
      \draw (18) -- (27);

       \draw (19) -- (20);
      \draw (19) -- (24);
      \draw (19) -- (23);
      \draw (21) -- (25);
      \draw (21) -- (26);

            \draw (22) -- (25);
      \draw (22) -- (26);

      \draw (21) -- (22);
            \draw (27) -- (23);
      \draw (24) -- (26);

      \draw (26) -- (25);
      \draw (27) -- (25);

      \draw (27) -- (13);
      \draw (27) -- (12);


      \draw (9) -- (8);
      \draw (3) -- (2);

      \draw (24) -- (26);
      \draw (27) -- (23);

       \draw (19) -- (20);
      \draw (20) -- (4);
       \draw (20) -- (6);
      \draw (20) -- (5);

            \draw (4) -- (6);

             \draw (25) -- (18);
      \draw (25) -- (17);
       \draw (25) -- (22);
      \draw (25) -- (21);




\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: try the argument: `width=\linewidth` between the squared braces

Comment: Do you really want to use less than 20% of the horizontal space and less than 10% of the vertical space for the body of your document? You have specified an enormous `papersize` but only a small proportion of it is available for the content of your document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page settings are dubious. If you use normal page settings, and `\resizebox` from `graphicx` package, things settle down:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage[papersize={500mm, 1000mm}, text={90mm, 90mm}]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture} [
      line/.style = {draw, thick, -latex},
      dot/.style = {draw, fill=black},
%      scale=0.2
      ]
             \coordinate (0) at (0cm, 0cm);
             \coordinate (1) at (-20cm, 9cm);
             \coordinate (9) at (20cm, 9cm);


      \coordinate (2) at (-40cm, 30cm);
      \coordinate (8) at (40cm, 30cm);

      \coordinate (3) at (-40cm, 50cm);
      \coordinate (7) at (40cm, 50cm);



            \coordinate (4) at (-30cm, 70cm);
            \coordinate (6) at (30cm, 70cm);


            \coordinate (5) at (0cm, 85cm);


            \coordinate (10) at (0cm, 5cm);


             \coordinate (11) at (-15cm, 15cm);
             \coordinate (16) at (15cm, 15cm);


      \coordinate (12) at (-10cm, 22cm);
                  \coordinate (15) at (10cm, 22cm);


      \coordinate (13) at (-25cm, 26cm);
            \coordinate (14) at (25cm, 26cm);


      \coordinate (22) at (-30cm, 57cm);
      \coordinate (18) at (30cm, 57cm);


            \coordinate (19) at (0cm, 43cm);

            \coordinate (20) at (0cm, 55cm);


            \coordinate (21) at (-20cm, 45cm);
            \coordinate (17) at (20cm, 45cm);


             \coordinate (23) at (-12cm, 40cm);
      \coordinate (24) at (12cm, 40cm);


      \coordinate (25) at (8cm, 51cm);


            \coordinate (26) at (-30cm, 34cm);
            \coordinate (27) at (30cm, 34cm);

      \draw (0) -- (1);
      \draw (0) -- (9);
      \draw (0) -- (10);
      \draw (0) -- (16);
      \draw (0) -- (11);

      \draw (1) -- (10);
      \draw (1) -- (2);
      \draw (1) -- (11);


      \draw (2) -- (4);
      \draw (2) -- (3);
      \draw (2) -- (22);


      \draw (3) -- (4);
      \draw (3) -- (22);


      \draw (4) -- (5);
      \draw (4) -- (6);
 \draw (4) -- (20);
  \draw (4) -- (22);


      \draw (5) -- (6);
      \draw (5) -- (20);


      \draw (6) -- (20);
        \draw (6) -- (7);
      \draw (6) -- (18);
       \draw (6) -- (8);

        \draw (7) -- (18);
      \draw (7) -- (8);

            \draw (9) -- (8);

            \draw (9) -- (16);
            \draw (9) -- (10);

    \draw (16) -- (15);


      \draw (10) -- (11);
        \draw (10) -- (16);
      \draw (11) -- (12);
       \draw (12) -- (13);

      \draw (12) -- (27);
      \draw (12) -- (23);
       \draw (13) -- (27);
      \draw (13) -- (23);


      \draw (14) -- (26);
      \draw (14) -- (24);
       \draw (14) -- (15);
      \draw (15) -- (26);
      \draw (15) -- (24);

       \draw (17) -- (18);
      \draw (17) -- (25);
      \draw (17) -- (27);

      \draw (18) -- (25);
      \draw (18) -- (27);

       \draw (19) -- (20);
      \draw (19) -- (24);
      \draw (19) -- (23);
      \draw (21) -- (25);
      \draw (21) -- (26);

            \draw (22) -- (25);
      \draw (22) -- (26);

      \draw (21) -- (22);
            \draw (27) -- (23);
      \draw (24) -- (26);

      \draw (26) -- (25);
      \draw (27) -- (25);

      \draw (27) -- (13);
      \draw (27) -- (12);


      \draw (9) -- (8);
      \draw (3) -- (2);

      \draw (24) -- (26);
      \draw (27) -- (23);

       \draw (19) -- (20);
      \draw (20) -- (4);
       \draw (20) -- (6);
      \draw (20) -- (5);

            \draw (4) -- (6);

             \draw (25) -- (18);
      \draw (25) -- (17);
       \draw (25) -- (22);
      \draw (25) -- (21);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, you can also use `scale` option in `tikzpicture` options (which I have commented in code).